# Change element id and use a new function on that ID

Tags: javascript

I am trying to construct a thumbnail slideshow with javascript. I am very new to Javascript so my way of doing it might be a little strange...

The problem I am running into is that I have a main image, and then I have 4 thumbnails. When I click on the first thumbnail it changes the main image, and the first thumbnail. But when I click on the changed thumbnail it needs to change the main image with a different photo (the one that corresponds to the new thumbnail)

I initialize my functions with a call like this:

```
document.getElementById('thumb1').onclick=thumbs1;
```

Which uses this function:

```
function thumbs1(){
    num1 = 1;
    num2 = 0;
    var src1 = largeArray[num1];
    var src2 = thumbArray[num2];
    document.getElementById('main').src=src1;
    document.getElementById('one').src=src2;
    document.getElementById('one').id='change';
}
```

And I am trying to change the id of the new thumbnail to "change" and call another function like this:

```
document.getElementById('change').onclick=changed;
```

And this used the following function:

```
function changed(){
    num1 = 0;
    var src1 = largeArray[num1];
    document.getElementById('change').src=src1;
    document.getElementById('change').id='one';
}
```

When using Firebug I found the error, and I believe it is being caused by the fact that the call to `document.getElementById('change').onclick=changed;`. The browser can not find the Element Id "change" because I have not called the function which changed the ID yet.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem. (I know the code is of low quality... I am teaching my self)

Here is a live link to the page: [My Page](http://www.chrisfrank.me/eclass/js/lesson5.html#)

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: It would be easier -- and better, IMHO-- to keep the ID of the image constant and change up the src attribute each time it's clicked.

Comment: When the image changes after the first time it is clicked I need it to call another function to change the main image to the default one. How would I call a function on the same ID but change it to a different SRC? Thanks for the quick response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var array = //id's of your images here. you could type them static or search your document for images and get their id attribute.

document.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    var clicked_image = e.target || e.srcElement; //using jquery can help with this cause older versions of IE are stupid, but depends on if you want to support them. 
    var id = clicked_image.getAttribute(id);
    var temp = document.getElementById("main").src;

    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        if(array[i] == id){
            document.getElementById("main").src = clicked_image.src;
            clicked_image.src = temp;
        }
    }
})
```

That's pretty quick and dirty, you would be better off assigning `eventlisteners` to just your images. You would use the same syntax as above, but it should give you an idea of what to do.

With this you don't have to worry about what image got clicked, you just change the main, and you change the thumb to what the main was. So you eliminate the hassle of trying to keep track of what each image is.

Comment: Also since your learning javascript, I would stay away from jquery. Once you have a solid foundation and you know what's going on, then jquery can take some of the pain our of selectors and the cross browser crap.

Comment: Thanks for you help! I have been using jquery for the last year or so, and it has definitely hindered my ability to learn Javascript. But I am fixing that now. Thanks again!

Comment: @ChrisFrank yep, one of the worst things I see in web developers, people who have no idea what to do if jquery doesn't have a built in function/plugin for what they want to do.